# Scattering in pion-proton-neutron theory with isospin conservation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, isospin-symmetry

I am following Sidney Coleman's lecture of Quantum Field Theory.

In ch 24.3 (starting from page 516) he discussed how to use isospin concept to consider the scattering of one nucleon and one pion. I understand that nucleon has isospin $I=1/2$ and pion has isospin $I=1$, and therefore the total isospin when we combine nucleon and pion will be $I_{tot}=3/2$ and $I_{tot} = 1/2$.

The interacting Lagrangian is given by
$\mathcal{L}_{I} = g \vec{\Phi} \cdot \bar{N} i \gamma_{5} \vec{\tau} N$
where $\vec{\Phi} = (\phi_{1},\phi_{2},\phi_{3})$ is the pion field written as a isovector, $N = [p\ n]^{T}$ is the isospinor where $p$ is the proton while $n$ is the nucleon field.

He then said that there will be only two scattering amplitudes we need to consider, one is the isospin-$1/2$ channel $\mathcal{A}_{1/2}$ and the other is the isospin-$3/2$ channel $\mathcal{A}_{3/2}$. These two scattering amplitudes are then enough to describe all the scattering process that can arise if we do scattering experiments from one nucleon and one pion, ignoring electromagnetic corrections.

My confusion is that, we know that $I_{tot}=3/2$ and $1/2$, which means that we have 6 possible states to consider

1. $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = 3/2$
2. $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = 1/2$
3. $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = -1/2$
4. $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = -3/2$
5. $I = 1/2$, $I_{3} = 1/2$
6. $I = 1/2$, $I_{3} = -1/2$

How do we know that the scattering from $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = 3/2$ to $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = 3/2$ is the same as the scattering from $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = 1/2$ to $I = 3/2$, $I_{3} = 1/2$, as it seems like both processes are described by a single scattering amplitude $\mathcal{A}_{3/2}$ in the isospin-$3/2$ channel?

Comment: I know that we can use Clebsch - Gordan coefficient to relate the total isospin eigenstate and the pion-nentron-proton state. What I am not sure is that how do we deduce that the transition between states with same I while different I_3 should have the same amplitude (like the example in my post). To me they describe different process, even though the total isopin I are same. Maybe that is what you said about "how to correlate amplitudes (components) of the same isomultiplet"? Could you elaborate it more? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So they do not have the same amplitude, what about the |amp|^2?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my understanding so far: in the pion-proton-neutron theory, we can compute various scattering amplitude between either proton&pion, neutron&proton and anything we want. However, what is now stated is that, although there are various kinds of scattering, we only need to know “two” scattering amplitudes to reconstruct all the scattering between proton, neutron and pion. And this scattering amplitude can be classified by the total isospin number I.

Comment: Therefore we only need to know the scattering amplitude from I = 3/2 to I = 3/2 (notice that I didn’t specify I_3 there) and I = 1/2 to I = 1/2 Of course, we need to form linear combination of states lablled by |I,I_3> to get the two particle state we want (like incoming proton-neutral states), this is how Clebsches helps.

Comment: But my main question is: how do we know the relation between, for example the transition from I = 3/2, I_3 = 3/2 to I = 3/2, I_3 = 3/2 and the one from I = 3/2, I_3 = 1/2 to I = 3/2, I_3 = 1/2? Is this also something that Clebsch can tell us? Sorry I am still new so my questions might seem weird, but I will appreciate if you could tell me more about this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, isospin is like angular momentum,
so, knowing that, in Condon-Shortley,
$$
J_-|jm\rangle = \sqrt {j(j+1)-m(m-1)}|j~ m-1\rangle ,  
$$
you have
$$
I_-|3/2~3/2\rangle = \sqrt{3} | 3/2 ~ 1/2\rangle,  
$$
hence, for an isoinvariant hamiltonian,
$$
  \langle 3/2~1/2|   H  |3/2~1/2\rangle= {1\over 3}  \langle 3/2~3/2|I_+ H I_-| 3/2~3/2\rangle\\=  {1\over 3}  \langle 3/2~3/2| H I_+ I_-| 3/2~3/2\rangle =  {1\over 3}  \langle 3/2~3/2| H (2I_3+I_- I_+)| 3/2~3/2\rangle \\
=    \langle 3/2~3/2 | H  | 3/2~3/2\rangle.
$$
The isospin ladder operators commute with the hamiltonian, and, of course, the raising operator annihilates the $I_3=3/2$ state.